# How to make two functions work separately and together in luascript? -software logitech GHUB

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I want this code to work together and separately when scrolllock is enabled. One using the mouse button(3) and the other the mouse button(2). Working separately they are working, however when I activate one the other does not work. I did a lot of research and it seems that there is a way to do it using a "coroutine", but I didn't find out how.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
local r = 350
local x = 350
local s = 50
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      local positions = {             -- Move `MoveMouseRelative` args to an 2d array.
          {-r,x},
          {-r,x},
          {r,x},
          {r,x},
          {r,-x},
          {r,-x},
          {-r,-x},
          {-r,-x},
      }
      local index = 1
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(positions[index][1], positions[index][2])        
        Sleep(s)
        index = (index % #positions) + 1 -- loop index when it reaches the array length.
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
      end
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
      repeat
      PressAndReleaseKey("p")
      Sleep(750)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write each "task" in its own coroutine and write a coroutine-friendly implementation of `Sleep()`.

```
local orig_Sleep = Sleep

local function Sleep(delay)
   local co, is_main = coroutine.running()
   if not is_main and co then
      local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
      repeat
         coroutine.yield(true)
      until GetRunningTime() >= tm
   else
      orig_Sleep(delay)
   end
end

local tasks = {}

local function add_task(task_function)
   table.insert(tasks, coroutine.wrap(
      function()
         repeat
            task_function()
            coroutine.yield()
         until nil
      end
   ))
end

local function task_manager()
   repeat
      Sleep(5)
      local active  -- true when at least one task is inside "Sleep" now
      for _, resume_task in ipairs(tasks) do
         active = resume_task() or active
      end
   until not active
end

add_task(
   function()
      if IsKeyLockOn"scrolllock" and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
         local r = 350
         local x = 350
         local s = 50
         local positions = { -- `MoveMouseRelative` args
            {-r,x},
            {-r,x},
            {r,x},
            {r,x},
            {r,-x},
            {r,-x},
            {-r,-x},
            {-r,-x},
         }
         local index = 1
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(positions[index][1], positions[index][2])
            Sleep(s)
            index = (index % #positions) + 1 -- loop index when it reaches the array length.
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
      end
   end
)

add_task(
   function()
      if IsKeyLockOn"scrolllock" and IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
         repeat
            PressAndReleaseKey("p")
            Sleep(750)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
      end
   end
)

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   task_manager()
end
```

Comment: It's returning this error "[string "LuaVM"]:18: attempt to index a nil value (global 'coroutine') Line Number:1". As I've never used "coroutine" I can't find why it's returning null on string 18

Comment: Indeed, unlike LGS, GHUB lacks `coroutine` Lua library.  Please send a message to Logitech support.  (Also try: GHUB Settings -> Send Error Report)  Probably this happened in 2020 when Lua `math` library was missed.  Two libraries had missed, but only `math` was returned back after users complained a lot about their scripts stopped working.